# Problem with Vegan:::varpart : how to calculate [a] and [a+b+c] Adj.R2?

Tags: vegan

I got different information on internet on the varpart calculation and so I am not sure I got the correct results.

Does the Adj.R2 for the full rda correspond to [a+b+c] (1) or to [a] (as in the R results and 2)?
Or did I misunderstood everything?
Many thanks
A

(1) according to: [https://sites.ualberta.ca/~ahamann/teaching/renr690/labs/Lab9e.pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Eahamann/teaching/renr690/labs/Lab9e.pdf)

(2) according to: https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop10/book-fr/partitionnement-de-la-variation.html

```
data(mite)
data(mite.env)
data(mite.pcnm)
mite.spe.hel <- decostand(mite, method = "hellinger")
mite.subs <- subset(mite.env, select = c(SubsDens, WatrCont))
mite.spat <- subset(mite.pcnm, select = names(spat.sel$terminfo$ordered))
mite.part <- varpart(mite.spe.hel, mite.subs, mite.spat)
mite.part$part  # extraire résultats

Total variation (SS): 27.205 
Variance: 0.39428 
No. of observations: 70 

Partition table:
  Df R.squared Adj.R.squared Testable
[a+b] = X1            2   0.32677       0.30667     TRUE          
#ab= RsquareAdj(rda(mite.spe.hel, mite.subs))$adj.r.squared
[b+c] = X2           10   0.52271       0.44181     TRUE         
#bc= RsquareAdj(rda(mite.spe.hel, mite.spat))$adj.r.squared
[a+b+c] = X1+X2      12   0.58764       0.50083     TRUE   
Individual fractions                                    
[a] = X1|X2           2                 0.05902     TRUE         
#= RsquareAdj(rda(mite.spe.hel, mite.subs, mite.spat))$adj.r.squared, but this should not correspond to [a+b+c]?
[b]                   0                 0.24765    FALSE
[c] = X2|X1          10                 0.19416     TRUE       
#= RsquareAdj(rda(mite.spe.hel, mite.spat, mite.subs))$adj.r.squared
[d] = Residuals                         0.49917    FALSE
---
  Use function ‘rda’ to test significance of fractions of interest
```

Comment: Neither your source (2) nor the R result claim that adjusted R^2 for the full model concerns individual fraction [a]. The R result says that [a] is an *individual* fraction of the full model, and corresponds to model X1|X2 or in vegan notation a formula with right-hand-side `~ X1 + Condition(X2)`, full model being `~ X1 + X2`.